# Количество вхождений свойства объекта в массиве объектов

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть массив объектов

> [ { "case": "foo", "count": 1 },  { "case": "foo", "count": 5 }, {
>   "case": "bar", "count": 10 } ]

Необходимо подсчитать количество кейсов с одинаковыми названиями и наибольшее значение свойства `count` для каждого названия кейса, в данном случае должен быть следующий результат:

```
foo: 2, maxCount: 5
bar: 1, maxCount: 10
```

Я делаю так но не совсем получается подсчет максимального `count` для каждой группы `case`:

```
let groupByUseCase = {};
    let maximum = 0;
    array.forEach(function(item) {
      let objStr = JSON.stringify(item.case);
      if (item.count > maximum) {
        groupByUseCase["maximum"] = item.count;
      }
      groupByUseCase[objStr] = groupByUseCase[objStr] ? ++groupByUseCase[objStr] : 1;
    });
console.log("group by use case: ", groupByUseCase);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = [
  { "case": "foo", "count": 1 },
  { "case": "foo", "count": 5 },
  { "case": "bar", "count": 10 }
];

//foo: 2, maxCount: 5
//bar: 1, maxCount: 10

let groupByUseCase = {};
data.forEach(function(item) {
  if (!groupByUseCase[item.case]) {
    groupByUseCase[item.case] = { maxCount: item.count };
    groupByUseCase[item.case][item.case] = 0;
  }
  if (item.count > groupByUseCase[item.case].maxCount) {
    groupByUseCase[item.case].maxCount = item.count;
  }
  groupByUseCase[item.case][item.case]++;
});
console.log("group by use case: ", groupByUseCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cellNames =
[
 {"case": "foo", "count": 1 },
 {"case": "foo", "count": 5 },
 {"case": "bar", "count": 10}
];

var groupByUseCase = {};

cellNames.forEach(function(item)
{
 var objStr = item.case;
 if(!groupByUseCase[objStr])
  groupByUseCase[objStr] = {maximum: 0, size: 0};

 if(item.count > groupByUseCase[objStr].maximum)
  groupByUseCase[objStr].maximum = item.count;

 groupByUseCase[objStr].size++;
});
console.log("group by use case: ", groupByUseCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let cellNames = [
  {"case": "foo", "count": 1},
  {"case": "foo", "count": 5},
  {"case": "bar", "count": 10}
];

let result = cellNames.reduce((prev, cur) => {
  if (!prev[cur.case]) {
    prev[cur.case] = {count: 1, maxCount: cur.count};
  } else {
    prev[cur.case].count++;
    prev[cur.case].maxCount = Math.max(prev[cur.case].maxCount, cur.count);
  }
  return prev;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```